# Referencing jQuery ui is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I would like to replace it in my server, so that I don't have to be connected to the internet. How can I add the following to my website?

I tried the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="jquery-ui.tabs.js"></script>
```

It' not working? I don't know what folders to download from jquery, I am using the ui tabs, so I placed the following folders in the embedded webserver:

```
jquery-ui.css
jquery.ui.tabs.js
```

Can someone help?

Comment: It's not working because `href=` attributes are always resolved relative to the page address.  Are you accessing this page locally via a `file://` URL or something else (you mention an "embedded webserver"... what do you mean).

Comment: I think you can treat an embedded webserver as just a regular webserver, but it is very limited in space.

Comment: So you need to put those files in the right place for the server.  You haven't shown how your embedded server is configured (i.e. where in the filesystem the HTML resides and how it's mapped to a local URL).

Comment: Jim - Are you saying to replace <link rel="stylesheet" href=".... with <link rel="stylesheet" file://jquery-ui.css/>  <--- is this the correct format?

Comment: No. Figure out how the embedded server maps a URL to a file and go from there.  It would help if you showed the URL you use when you're offline, and the filesystem path where the HTML file resides.

Comment: I am new to all this. I guess my url is: http://192.168.1.104/index.html  This is the way I place my files in the server: ftp://192.168.1.104  then from the view menu, I select the open ftp File Explorer, then I dump the file in there. I hope this is what your referring to?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40773/discussion-between-neil-porven-and-jim-garrison)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating internal widgets with jquery is not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850650/creating-internal-widgets-with-jquery-is-not-working) -- which is your own question. ***Please*** don't ask the same question multiple times. If you're not getting satisfactory answers, consider how you're asking the question and what information you're providing. You can edit and update your original question until you get an answer that's satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

use the jQuery Download Builder to download the jQuery UI package you need:

http://jqueryui.com/download/

or to just download jQuery UI with UI tabs

http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.10.3&components=1111111110010001111011111111111111